# how to keep a UINavigationController in a modelView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am a little confused about the management for UINavigationController to ModelView. I am having an UINavigationController in the RootView, and I want to popup another modelView from bottom to up based on RootView and in the meanwhile keep the NavigationController stays in the modelView so that I could still navigate to the next. How to implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create your navigation controller in the RootView. Suppose you want to display modal view on button click in RootView :

```
- (IBAction) showModalView
{
        YourModalView * aYourModalView = [[YourModalView alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourModalView" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aYourModalView];
        aYourModalView.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES ;

        [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navigation animated:YES];
        [aYourModalView release];
}
```

Now, your modal view has navigation controller and you can push VCs from modal view using :

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:aViewController animated:YES];
```

Hope it helps you...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

```
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated
```

method on `UINavigationController`. Just don't animate, and change the object at index 0 of that array to your new RootView.